# How to open a form in Access, automatically select a value in a combobox and display the detail?

Tags: ms-access, combobox

A user can select a value in a combo box and the detail automatically loads into the forms fields.  How can I automatically select a particular value when (or after) opening the form and get the detail to load?

I've managed to set the value of the ComboBox after opening the form, but the detail on the page doesn't change until I manually select a value in the ComboBox.

Comment: Have you tried a refresh or reload on the detail, which I assume is a sub-form.

Answer (score 1):

Is the subform built with code or more simply by setting the link master field to the combo and the link child field to the matched field for the bound column? For the most part, the second way is best as it does not require the After Update code for the combo to be triggered, which won't happen when the value is set via code.

Comment: I have just tested with a combo bound to a key field but displaying text and a subform with Link Master Field set to the combo and Link Child Field set to common key field. In the Load event, there is one line of code `Me.Combo1 = 3444`, which works, in that record 3444 is displayed in the subform, without any further code.

Comment: Have you tested on a form with no other code? What version of Access are you using?